# Disable cookies until user accepts them via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Is there a way to disable the cookies (when a visitor visits a website) and only enable them after the visitor gives permission for it? And all with javascript or php.

In the EU there are new rules that requires this permission from a visitor. When you visit a site, only cookies that collects analytics results like Google analytics may be enabled without permission. But when you use Google tag manager for remarketing and things like that, you should have it disabled on your site with a notification bar on top where the visitor can give permission to enable them.

Is there a way to make this happen with javascript or PHP or a combination of both?

Regards,
Robert

Comment: It's called cookie wall, there are multiple solutions for this. Simplest client-side, more robust involving proxy and backend.

Comment: `if (userAcceptedCookieLaw) { //write cookie } else { //show notice }`

Comment: @dfsq We don't want to use something like a cookie wall, because it creates a situation where a visitor may leave your webshop. And because the normal cookies (that are needed for a webshop to function) are allowed, you want the visitor to have the opportunity to look around in your webshop without having to make a decision in front.

Comment: So what, that just means that _you_ have to properly classify your cookies to begin with - and implement this hold-back-until-consent feature only for the ones that fall into the “bad” category.

Comment: (But you can not seriously argue that Google Analytics would fall under _“cookies that are needed for a webshop to function”_ ...)

Comment: @CBroe Yes I know, but it's a bit of a grey area... But they rules are telling me that for now, the google analytics script/cookie is allowed without permission from the visitor.

Comment: Fine, than you can output the code for _that_ regardless of whether the user accepted already or not. For other components that might try and set some of the “bad” cookies, you want to hold back on that until you got consent.

Comment: Could it be something like:
<?php if (VisitorAcceptsIt) { ?> // When accepted, store a cookie that saves the answer for 30 days and then let the Google Tag Manager run script below
<noscript>
 <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MJVLQMW" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: In the broadest sense - yes, something like that. (Although you might want to output the code for tracking when JavaScript _is_ enabled as well, right now that would only be the variant to track those users without.)

Comment: Hmm... You have a point there... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - its not hard....

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 if (!count($_COOKIE) && !$_REQUEST['i_will_accept_cookies']) {
     // user has not accepted cookies
     include($message_about_cookies);
     ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); // make sure later code doesn't drop them by accident
     // Even if not using sessions, it provides a convenient place
     // to store the user preferences for the duration of execution
     // NB you should also poll this setting before calling setcookie()
 } else {
     // user accepts cookies
     if (!count($_COOKIE)) {
         setcookie("i_accept_cookies", "", time() + 3600*24*7);
     }
     // session_start(); // uncomment if using sessions
     // ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1); // only required
                 // if you've got 0 in the config files
 }
```

You can run the above as an auto-prepend.

Your message about cookies should contain a link/form/script which sends the 'i_accept_cookies' message back to the server.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to give me an example about creating a form summit that triggers the 'i_accept_cookies'?

Comment: `<a href="http://yourserver/anything.php?i_accept_cookies=1">I accept cookies</a>` (where anything.php contains the code above)